# Cannot Update Data in Reactjs+Laravel App

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-api

I have an offer-adding feature in my app. my front end is on react js and the backend is on Laravel. I have created a route to update the data and called it using Axios but I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any type of Help will be appreciated Thank You!

> this is my route in api.php

```
Route::put('offers/{id}', 'Api\Offer\OfferController@update');
```

> This is my OfferController

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $offer = Offer::findOrFail($id);
    $offer->update($request->all());
    return $offer;
}
```

> This is my API call function for update

```
export const updateItem = (offertitle,offerdescription,vid,id) => {
return axios
    .put(
        `/api/offers/${id}`,
        {   
            offertitle:offertitle,
            offerdescription:offerdescription,
            vid:vid
        },
        {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        }
    )
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response)
    })
```

}

> OfferComponent

````
export default class Offer extends React.Component{
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      offertitle: '',
      offerdescription: '',
      editDisabled: false,
      offers: [],
      redirect: false,
      vid:'',
      offerid:''

    }

    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getAll()
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('user')) {
      vendorprofile().then(res => {
        this.setState({
          vid: res.user.vid
        })
      })

    }
    else {
      this.setState({ redirect: true });
    }
  }

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }

  getAll = () => {
    getList().then(data => {
      this.setState(
        {

          offertitle:'',
          offerdescription:'',
          offers: [...data]
        },
        () => {
          console.log(this.state.offers)
        }
      )
    })
  }

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    addItem({offertitle: this.state.offertitle, offerdescription: this.state.offerdescription,vid: this.state.vid}).then(() => {
      this.getAll()
    })
    this.setState({
      offertitle: '',
      offerdescription:'',
      vid:''
    })
  }

  onUpdate = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    updateItem({ offertitle: this.state.offertitle, offerdescription: this.state.offerdescription, offerid: this.state.offerid, vid: this.state.vid }).then(() => {
      this.getAll()
    })
    this.setState({
      offertitle: '',
      offerdescription: '',
      vid:'',
      editDisabled: ''

    })
    this.getAll()
  }

  onEdit = (offerid, e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    var data = [...this.state.offers]
    data.forEach((offers,index) => {
      if (offers.offerid === offerid) {
        this.setState({
          offerid: offers.offerid,
          offertitle: offers.offertitle,
          offerdescription: offers.offerdescription,
          editDisabled: true
        })
      }
    })
  }

  onDelete = (val, e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    deleteItem(val)

    var data = [...this.state.offers]
    data.filter(function (offers, index) {
      if (offers.offerid === val) {
        data.splice(index, 1)
      }
      return true
    })
    this.setState({ offers: [...data] })
  }

 render() {
    if (this.state.redirect) {
      return (
        <Redirect to="/stsignin" />
      )
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <Pane />
        <div className="container" style={{ marginTop : 150}}>
        <form>
          <div className="form-group">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-12">
                <label>OFFER TITLE</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="offertitle"
                  name="offertitle"
                  value={this.state.offertitle || ''}
                  onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
                />

                  <label>OFFER DESCRIPTION</label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="offerdescription"
                    name="offerdescription"
                    value={this.state.offerdescription || ''}
                    onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
                  />

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {!this.state.editDisabled ? (
            <button
              type="submit"
              onClick={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}
              className="btn btn-success btn-block"
            >
              Submit
                        </button>
          ) : (
              ''
            )}
          {this.state.editDisabled ? (
            <button
              type="submit"
              onClick={this.onUpdate.bind(this)}
              className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
            >
              Update
                        </button>
          ) : (
              ''
            )}
        </form>
        <table className="table">
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>OFFER_TITLE</th>
                <th>OFFER_DESCRIPTION</th>
              </tr>
            {this.state.offers.map((offers,index) => (

              <tr key={index}>
                <td className="text-left">{offers.offertitle}</td>
                <td className="text-left">{offers.offerdescription}</td>
                <td className="text-right">
                  <button
                    href=""
                    className="btn btn-info mr-1"
                    disabled={this.state.editDisabled}
                    onClick={this.onEdit.bind(
                      this,
                      offers.offerid
                    )}
                  >
                    Edit
                                    </button>
                  <button
                    href=""
                    className="btn btn-danger"
                    disabled={this.state.editDisabled}
                    onClick={this.onDelete.bind(
                      this,
                      offers.offerid
                    )}
                  >
                    Delete
                                    </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

}```
````

Comment: what's the response from server ?

Comment: I get error 404

Answer (score 0):

Error 404 Might mean that the offer specified in the link doesn't exist and thus can't be updated. Check if you have an order with the id that you are searching in the database. However, posting your entire response might show us more information. A simple 404 is pretty vague, you might want to copy paste that in.

That being said, i recommend using Eloquent for these kind of routes. You can basically change your route to `/offers/{offer}` and then instead of typing $id as a variable for that function and then finding the offer by id you can just simply query `$offer->update(your_data)` and it would work as expected. It is exactly the same thing but just keeps it cleaner and removes any basic mistakes

Comment: I have checked the API routes again they are working fine I think I have done something wrong in Frontend.